# Best way to declare product variables in woocommerce theme development?

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to be able to use the product variables across all templates. Where should I store them? In Woocommerce templates folder? Example:

`$productTitle = $product->get_name();`
`$productSlug = $product->get_slug();`

I need to be able to echo these variables and I don't want to declare them more than once.
`<h3> $productTitle </h3>`

What's the better and cleaner way of doing it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you would like to "store" them? If not, you can simply do it like this:

```php
<h3><?php echo esc_html( $product->get_name() ); ?></h3>
```